# Regex expression for setting a timer

Tags: regex, timer

Okay i'm still learning about Regex and i'm making a voice assistant for my phone and i want it to accept any of the following:

```
set the timer for 5 minutes
set timer for 5 minutes
set a timer for 5 minutes
set a goddamn timer for 5 minutes
set this timer for 5 minutes
```

Basically i want every word between `set` and `timer`.

I'm trying this but it doesn't work.

```
set  (the|a|.) timer for [1-9]{1,} (minute|minutes)
```

Another command is about canceling the timer:

```
cancel the timer   
timer cancel  
cancel timer
```

Basically if the words "cancel" and "timer" appear in any combination in the sentence it should cancel the timer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [enjoy](http://regex101.com/r/hT6xT6) :)

Comment: Thanks, that site has some nice features.

Comment: You're welcome, note that the website uses PHP's implementation of PCRE, so you have to take a look at the difference between your regex flavor and PHP PCRE

Answer (score 2):

You... could do something like that:

```
set(.*?)timer for [1-9]{1,} minutes?
```

This capture group will catch anything. And the `?` makes the `s` optional.

For the other one, I guess you could have something like

```
(cancel).*?(timer)|(timer).*?(cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl it would be something like this:

```
$value =~ s/^set (.*?)timer//s;
```

Since it is in parenthesis it will match it to $1, if you need to replace it put something between the //